# PostgreSQL Unique Key column contains duplicate records

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PG 9.6 with unique key constraint on it. I took the backup using pg_dump and restore it in PG12. While restoring I got error for the table mentioned with unique key constraint failed. After checked in PG 9.6, Column contains few duplicates.

Here Question is

1. How is it possible for containing duplicates in column with unique key constraint ?
2. Also, how to fix this error in PG12 without deleting duplicates (PG 9.6 contains duplicates)?

Comment: Which 9.6 version is that exactly? Which data type is the PK column? There are some cases where upgrading the operating system could break indexes due to different collation sort/comparison behaviour

Comment: aakash=# \d det                                   Table "public.det"
      Column      |  Type   |                                 Modifiers
------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 det_id           | integer | not null default nextval('det_det_id_seq'::regclass)
 det              | text    | not null
 vid              | text    |
Indexes:
    "det_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (det_id)
    "det_det_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (det)
Referenced by: TABLE "can" CONSTRAINT "can_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (det_id) REFERENCES det(det_id)

Comment: This is the table structure, constraint failing on det_det_key

Comment: The exact version is PostgreSQL 9.6.3